# add an image tag in a div

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

I making a blog part with a buyed template.
I'm looking for add image in div. Something like that.

```
<div class="card card-raised card-background" style="background-image: url('<%= image_tag blog.couverture.url(:hd) %>')">
                            <div class="card-body">
...
```

Unfortunatly it's not working. So I looking for help after one hour of research on internet.
Thank you for you help.

Comment: Better you check [this](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag). `<div><%= image_tag(blog.couverture.url(:hd), class: "card card-raised card-background") %></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Your image must be in "assets/images" folder on your rails proyect, then try this:

```
<div>
  <img src="<%= asset_path 'image_name.format' %>" alt="">
</div>
```